# Replace webpage buttons when visited by outdated browser

Tags: html, css

heI've been working on a webpage for my fathers new company, and ran into a small problem.
The thing I made looked nice on my computer and decided to upload and sent the link to my father. He said the buttons were wrong etc, so he has an old version of the webbrowsers.
this is the html & css code for one button

```
<div class="menu-g">

            <a href="genuine.html">
                <span class="menu-g-slide-text">Genuine</span>
                <img src="images/menug.png" alt="icon" />
            </a>
        </div>

.mid .menu .menu-g {
background: #e5e5e5;
height: 90px;
width: 170px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
border: 2px solid #e10613;
box-shadow: 
    0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 
    1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-radius: 4px;
clear: both;
margin: 10px 0px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
left: 50px;


}

.mid .menu .menu-g img{
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 5px;
border: none;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.mid .menu .menu-g .menu-g-slide-text{
position: absolute;
font-size: 36px;
left: 20px;
color: #333;
opacity: 0;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;  
}

.mid .menu .menu-g:hover{
box-shadow: 
    0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 
    1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
border-top: 7px solid #e10613;
border-bottom: 7px solid #e10613;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
position: relative;
top: -5px;

}
.mid .menu .menu-g:hover img{
transform: scale(10);
opacity: 0;

}

.mid .menu .menu-g:hover .menu-g-slide-text {
opacity: 1;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;
}

.mid .menu .menu-g:active {
position: relative;
top: -2px;
background: #CCC;
box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;

}
```

Now I just want if someone with an outdated webbrowser visits the page, it'll just change to button to a simple squared box with a word it as button.

How do I do that exactly?

Thanks in advance & kind regards
Dave.

Comment: Use conditional css using libraries like Modernizr or specific css files for browsers.

Comment: check this website [CanIuse](http://www.caniuse.com/) and click on each property of CSS3 and HTML5 you're using to know which browsers and version supporting them, then as @eric.itzhak said use Modernizr or alternative css for non-supporting browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error probably arises from the use of some CSS2/3 attributes. Check [this matrix](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS) and CSS3 additions list to find out more.

If you have to support ancient IE browsers, say IE5, you can use [conditional comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) to load alternate CSS. Another solution is  feature detection with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), as suggested also in the comment above.

UPDATE: [this](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE) library may relief some pain when working with old Internet Explorer.

Anyway, I would strongly advice your father to update his browser to a more recent and secure one.

Besides, dissolve the `span` and put the image in the CSS `background` property, as it is not part of the content, rather of the presentation.

Comment: oh yes you're right about that span ;)! I'm going to mess around with those libraries a bit and hopefully it'll be fixed by tonight.